# Meaning of =3D in malicious URLs

Tags: http, xss, sql-injection, urlencode

My server logs show a many attempts to access non existing sides. These are the "usual" bots scanning for known vulnerabilities. Many of the URLs contain `=3D`, e.g.

```
/?q=3Duser%2Fpassword&name%5B%23p=
/user/register/?element_parents=3Daccou=
/wp-admin/admin-post.php?swp_debug=3Dlo=
```

`%3D` is the url encoded value of `=` so I would expect to find `%3D` within the URL but not `=3D`. However, `=3D` can be found all over the logs. What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=3D` is an example of a [Quoted-Printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) for ASCII 0x3D, or the equals sign character (`=`).

You don't usually see this in URLs. It's not the normal encoding to use. It's a standard MIME type, an alternative to using base64. It looks like the request is expecting the app to decode the query string using Quoted-Printable, and then use the resulting path in some further redirect.