# What type of encoding is this - Sendgrid inbound parse email content

Tags: c#, encoding, sendgrid

I have sendgrid inbound implemented, When my API receives the email content from sendgrid, I see this in the HTML content of the email. **Can someone tell me what kind of encoding this is?**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8">
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"> P {margin-top:0;margin-bo=
ttom:0;} </style>
</head>
```

Looks like `=` is being replaced by `=3D`. I have never heard or seen of such a thing, I know URL encoding does replace `=` with a `%3D` but this one looks different.

I have a piece of text elsewhere within the email which has a `=` in it, and that too gets replaced by `=3D` causing issues. I can simply do a

`emailContent.Replace("=3D", "=")`

in my API, but I want to understand what type of encoding is this so I fix it in a proper way so that no other special character in the future could cause an issue.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560325/meaning-of-3d-in-malicious-urls

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the link above points to this in Wikipedia: [Quoted Printable Encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)